# Way for tengu to pounce with a sword

Tags: pathfinder-1e, races

I have heard of some way for a tengu to pounce (or at least move+full attack) with a sword, but i can't find anything on it.

Answer (score 6):

That would be the [Swordmaster Tengu](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/featured-races/arg-tengu/swordmaster-rogue-tengu) using the **Tiger Trance** obtained at 3rd level. It's a rogue archetype exclusive for tengus and was introduced on the [Advanced Race Guide](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8rv2?Pathfinder-Roleplaying-Game-Advanced-Race-Guide).

> **Tiger Trance** (Ex): The swordmaster pounces upon her opponents, striking with the ferocity and brute force of a wild tiger. While in this trance, a swordmaster can make a combat maneuver check against an opponent within charge range. If she succeeds, **she may charge that opponent and make a full attack against that opponent**.